# Range of Bluetooth on iphone with other devices

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, connection

I know bluetooth on iphone is class 2 and range is 30 feet. But i tried connecting 2 iphone via bluetooth and it's range is 40 - 50m.
What happens when I connect the iPhone with a class 1 Bluetooth device? what is range?
Can anyone give me an explanation?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bluetooth power classes from Spec v4.2.
[image]

Typically two class1 devices can communicate over 100meters. where as Class2 devices communicate till 10 meters. mixing them doesn't give the expected range as the Transmitter of the Class2 device has too low power to reach the class1 device, hence the total range remains at 10 meters. please also note that Dynamic power control is used by Bluetooth Classic to adjust the power according to the distance. see the following Bluetooth LMP level messages.
[image]

May be this [link](http://electronicdesign.com/communications/understanding-wireless-range-calculations) will help you understand the relationship between Transmit power and Range.